# SQLalchemy specify which index to use

Tags: python, sql, indexing, sqlalchemy

Is there a way in SQLalchemy to tell the query which index to use?

The reason I need this is that the SQL queries it generates use the "wrong" index - there exists an index for exactly the two fields that I have and it doesn't use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you can use [with_hint()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_hint) for this.

e.g.

```
session.query(Model).with_hint(Model, 'USE INDEX col1_index')
```

Honestly, I didn't really know about this; I discovered it by finding 'USE INDEX' in their [ORM tests](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/test/orm/test_query.py).

Comment: I got it to work with 'USE INDEX (col1_index)' statement in mysql

Comment: For those who are using MS SQL Server or Azure SQL Database remember to specify `dialect_name` parameter when using `with_hint`: `session.query(Model).with_hint(Model, 'WITH(INDEX(col1_index))', 'mssql')`