# Sqlalchemy how to use force index?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I create an uniq index and a composite index for a mysql table:

```
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_idx_on_source` (`id`,`hour`,`platform`,`type`,`first_level`(60),`second_level`(120)),
  KEY `idx_on_source` (`id`,`hour`,`type`)
```

Uniq index is to prevent repeated data to store mysql, and composite index to improve query performance.

but the sql will use the uniq index when I query.

**explain** result:

[image]

I hope to use index `idx_on_source` not `uniq_idx_on_source`:

I found a answer as below:

> [SQLalchemy specify which index to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738499/sqlalchemy-specify-which-index-to-use)

but it  doesn't work for me!

My code:

```
db.session.query(Source)
          .with_hint(Source, 'USE INDEX (idx_on_source)')\
          .filter(hour >= :begin).all()
```

I output the sql by `str()` method:

```
str(db.session.query(Source)
          .with_hint(Source, 'USE INDEX (idx_on_source)')\
          .filter(hour >= :begin))
```

Output:

> 'SELECT source.id AS source_id,...... FROM source_stat \nWHERE source_stat.hour >= :hour'

but `USE INDEX (idx_on_source)` doesn't output!

Anyone has good idea?

Comment: @univerio I print the sql, didn't find the `use index (idx_on_source)` statement.

Comment: How did you print the SQL? What did you get? What's `model_name`? Can you post the code necessary so that we will be able to reproduce your lack of hint in the produced query?